# why is DataInputStream.readline adding strange bytes at the beginning of string

Tags: c#, java, android, xmlserializer, readline

Sending XML from C# Server and receiving it it in Android Java client

This is what the received XML look likes:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>.....
```

This is the c# send code

```
// convert the class WorkItem to xml
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WorkItem));
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, p);

// send the xml version of WorkItem to client
byte[] data = memoryStream.ToArray();
clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Console.WriteLine(" send.." + data);
clientStream.Close();
```

In Java i just do:

```
in = new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
String XMlString = in.readLine();
```

Everything is working if i every time remove the 3 first characters from `XMlString`.
I would really like to do this in a better way if it's possible

*UPDATE adding the Android java client

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Long... params) {

    textTopInfo.setText("Loading workitems..");

    DataOutputStream out = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;

    try {

        Socket skt = new Socket(Consts.SERVER_URL_1, Consts.SERVER_PORT_1);
        skt.setSoTimeout(10000); //10 sec timout
        out = new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
        in = new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());

        // check valid user id
        String id = prefs.getString("id", "");

        if(id.equals(""))
            return "Open menu and enter User Id";

        String theString =  Consts.PUSH_GET_WORKITEM + ":" + id ;

        out.write(theString.getBytes());

        BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
        String XMlString = d.readLine();

            // here I remove the BOM
        XMlString = XMlString.substring(3);

        Log.d(TAG, "GF");   

        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("WorkItem", WorkItem.class);
        xstream.alias("OneItem", OneItem.class);
        pl = (WorkItem)xstream.fromXML(XMlString);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return "cannot connect to server " + e.toString();

    }finally{
        //kill out/in
        try {
            if(out != null)
                out.close();
            if(in!=null)
                in.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
    return "here is the list";
}
```

Comment: Sending data like this is error prone. Why don't you just zip the XML string and send it over. In the other side, just unzip and process

Comment: what is skt in in = new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream()); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the method readLine is deprecated in Java 1.7; from the javadocs:

readLine()
Deprecated. 
This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the BufferedReader.readLine() method. Programs that use the DataInputStream class to read lines can be converted to use the BufferedReader class by replacing code of the form:
     DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);

with:
     BufferedReader d
          = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

Comment: try the following change in your code: BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Doesn't answer the question where the extra three characters came from.

Comment: I did put it in a comment and I did say try.

Comment: @Tom actually got it working with your help and this change in the c# code.. XmlTextWriter fs = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false));

Answer (score 2):

The three initial bytes is the UTF8 BOM (Byte ordering mark). You will need to tell your Java code to use the same encoding.

Comment: how? Or maybe I should go with GETah comment and just zip it

Comment: @Erik try something like `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))`